# Появилась красная надпись на страницах сайта

Tags: вирусы

Как убрать? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Появилась красная надпись "AVERTISSEMENT DE SÉCURITÉ : traitez l’URL ci-dessous comme un mot de passe et ne la partagez avec personne. ADVERTENCIA DE SEGURIDAD: trata la dirección URL si fuera tu contraseña y no la compartas con nadie." На страницах сайта, не на всех на некоторых.

Comment: И как вы себе представляете получить помощь от нас? Если сами не справляетесь, то наймите опытного программиста, дайте ему доступ на сайт и он решит проблему. А телепатически вам не помочь.

Comment: Я предполагал, что кто-то, вероятно, сталкивался с таким вопросом и мог подсказать, хотя бы направление где искать источник проблемы. Дело в том что я и по сети много искал и у специалистов спрашивал, в том числе у хостинга... Возможно Вы правы, что надо искать специалистом, а не тут задавать вопросы, но я всё-таки надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Вам уже подсказали - нанять программиста. Это самый разумный путь, который можно выбрать, вы сами не справитесь.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я так понимаю. Других "мнений" не будет, учитывая некоторую категоричность в Вашем ответе. Ну, что же, и на это Благодарю.
Извините, если побеспокоил, возможно, Вы правы, не стоило тратить время ни ваше ни моё...
Ещё раз простите.

Comment: @Eruption, все, что можно предположить субъективно - вы или уже пробовали, или не создали фундамент для определенных действий. К примеру, можно было бы восстановить сайт из бэкапа, но делали ли вы такие бэкапы: толи у вас локальная версия сайта, толи бэкап на хостинге?

Comment: добрый человек сломал ваш сайт и предупредил вас, а вы убрать. в следующий раз сломает ботовод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

взять и убрать её руками из кода. и поменять пароли в ftp

Comment: В коде надписи нет. Она "гуляет" по странице...

Comment: Значит посмотрите в записях в базе.